# Get Haskell programs to assume a UTF8 locale under wine

Tags: windows, haskell, character-encoding, wine, codepages

I am trying to use GHC on wine to build one of my Haskell applications for windows. So far, this works well, but I am stuck running my test suite, which is intended to be run in an UTF8-locale (`LANG=C.utf8` for example.)

Unfortunately, under wine, the Haskell runtime always believes I want to use a non-unicode codepage:

```
$ wine ghc -e 'GHC.IO.Encoding.CodePage.localeEncoding'
CP850
$ LANG=C.utf8 wine ghc -e 'GHC.IO.Encoding.CodePage.localeEncoding'
CP437
$ LC_ALL=C.utf8 wine ghc -e 'GHC.IO.Encoding.CodePage.localeEncoding'
CP437
```

Besides changing the actual code to set the encoding of all handles: How would I make the Haskell program use UTF-8 (i.e. codepage 65001) here?

Comment: You may find this alternative way to set environment variables helpful. If, that is, the environment has anything to do with it. https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/environment-variables

Comment: I have no reason to believe that environment variables influence the codepage – unfortunately.

Comment: Also, have you tried the stronger `LC_ALL` instead of `LANG`? I'm just throwing out guesses here.

Comment: yes, I did. Amended question for completeness.

Comment: Would running the test suite through a Windows batch file that sets the codepage help?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: Possibly, but how do I set it? `chcp` is not available in WINE, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Oh. Then I don't know either. I found one small thing: [Wine docs recommend](http://wiki.winehq.org/TestingLanguages) always spelling the suffix in the official form `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a Wine/Haskell setup here, so take this with many grains of salt. It looks [GHC.IO.Encoding](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/GHC-IO-Encoding.html) has what might be the right pieces for this:

```
setLocaleEncoding :: TextEncoding -> IO () 
utf8 :: TextEncoding
```

You could try making your test programs `setLocaleEncoding utf8` before they get going. This isn't quite what you wanted, but if it works it seems easier than setting it separately for each handle.

Comment: Thanks. I’d really like something that does not modify the code, so that I’m able to test the program as if it was running on the users’ machine with utf8 enabled. I’ll keep searching.

Comment: This won't work because `setLocaleEncoding` does not influence `localeEncoding`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:localeEncoding. Quite utterly confusing, TBH.

Also it won't change anything for child processes that might be spawned. The only reliable way I could find was via env vars.

Comment: @SebastianGraf Oy, `localeEncoding` looks like a hideous mess that ideally wouldn't exist at all. Do you know how to set up the environment variables under Wine? If so, you should probably add your own answer.

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't. I just found this thread while googling for a solution *not* involving env vars. Apparently there is none.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works for Wine, but have you tried using the `CHCP` command to set the current Windows code page?

Comment: That is what I recommend my users on real windows. Unfortunately, that command is not available in WINE.

Comment: Pity... Oh well, was worth a try!